# Сегментация текста

Tags: c++, python, opencv, машинное-обучение, обработка-изображений

Добрый день всем.

Я пытаюсь распознать последовательность из 6 цифр с картинки с помощью глубокого обучения. Для препроцессинга я использую библиотеку OpenCV. Первым делом я избавляюсь от шума с помощью [морфологических операций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) и делаю пороговое преобразование. Далее я ищу компоненты связности и нахожу минимальные ограничивающие прямоугольники.
Проблема в том, что последовательность каждый раз искажается случайным образом и какие-то цифры могут быть меньше по размеру, а какие-то больше. Какие-то цифры могут слипаться между собой.

На первом изображении найдено 4 компоненты связности, одна из которых содержит 3 цифры, которые нужно отделить друг от друга.
На втором изображении найдена одна компонента связности, которая содержит 6 цифр, которые тоже нужно отделить.

Подскажите, существуют ли какие-нибудь способы разделения слипшихся символов? Как провести более-менее приемлемую сегментацию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На исходном изображении цифры окрашены в разные цвета?

Comment: @isnullxbh нет. Исходное изображение находится слева, а справа уже после преобразования. Т.е не цветное.

Comment: Вы решили задачу?